# How to delete a line based on a regex string in Powershell?

Tags: command-line, powershell, filesystems, script, regex

I want to validate if the line above a certain line is there, then ok. if else, then delete that line and remove the empty space ? Can this be done in powershell? please help

If before all lines starting with "^37," if line starts with 33, then OK. Else, delete that line and remove the empty space as well. Now, there are more than hundred thousand instances like this issue in my file. Please help...its very urgent.

TestData.txt file:-

```
03,201779,,01354,73923309,,,TEST2,7962753,,,0343,5087632,,/#end of line
04,399,777873,,,,text234,,,,/ 
33,TEST1,,,0343,,93493,,,343,,,,TEST3,,,,,,/
37,TEST37,text
49,24605597,6,343,343,343,,,3434,,,/
```

Comment: I don't understand your condition "If before all lines starting with "^37,""

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code and any error info, so we are in a better position to guide you. As posted, you are asking us to write this from scratch for you. Sites like SU/SO, etc... are not free script writing services, as many regularly state around here. What you are asking for can easily be accomplished using ```Select-String``` cmdlet, and a bit more logic manipulation with its ```-Context``` switch. ```Get-Help -Name Select-String -Examples```. Many examples exist all over the web as well as on SU and SO. Just use the search box provided above to find them.

Comment: Yet, as noted by '@tukan', your use case is not explained well, as well as you not showing what you expect your results to be.

Comment: Not clear for me too, please explain explicitly your aim with an example and post what did you try as code until now, otherwise we can't help you without more informations ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following cmdlets:

```
#Get the file's content and join each line with newline character
#because by default splits lines by newline. So, the need to rejoin the lines 
$text = [string]::Join("`n", (Get-Content a.txt))

#Find and replace the pattern, then output the result to file
#The file's content is replaced
[regex]::Replace($text, "^3[^3].+`n^(37.+)", '$1', "Multiline") | Out-file a.txt
```

Replace `a.txt` with your filename.